# What is the expression for "take a bite"?

Tags: phrase-request, expressions

Suppose I want to say

> After ELL was launched it *took a bite* in the traffic of ELU's traffic.

Here by *took a bite* I want to convey that ELL has snatched some of the traffic of ELU. So what is the common ideal expression to convey the same meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To say that it took away some of EL&U's traffic, *took a bite* could be appropriate. However, it would be used with *out of*, not *in*.

> After ELL was launched, it *took a bite out of* EL&U's traffic.

Additional reference: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+a+bite+out+of

Answer (score 1):

You could also say

> After ELL was launched, it **diverted some** of EL&U's traffic.
>
> After ELL was launched, it **stole some** of EL&U's traffic.